# add pollution to the air VS add air pollution

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence,

> While most printing companies use toxic inks that **add air pollution**,
> this company uses non-toxic inks that don't.

I think it should be

> While most printing companies use toxic inks that **add pollution to the air**,
> this company uses non-toxic inks that don't.

> While most printing companies use toxic inks that **add to air pollution**,
> this company uses non-toxic inks that don't.

"add air pollution" should be used as follows,

> Certain people add air pollution to their reasons for not living in big cities.

> We should add air pollution control.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own inclination would be to use ***...toxic inks add pollution to the air***.

Everyone would know what you meant if you said *...add air pollution*, but strictly speaking "air pollution" is not a substance but a condition - and hence not something which you can "add" to something else.

You could, however,  say  ***...toxic inks increase air pollution***.

So either of the two highlighted would be fine - in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

"Add air pollution" is perfectly fine, as it already shows how pollition goes into the air. There is no need for changing this.